# Json data manipulation using python 2.7[Redhat6.7]

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unix

I am a bit newbie to python and its data manipulation dict, list.

So I have following JSON data :

```
{'Namelist': {'thomas': {'gender': 'male', 'age': '23'}, 'david': {'gender':  'male'}, 'jennie': {'gender': 'female', 'age': '23'}, 'alex': {'gender': 'male'}}, 'selectors': {'naming': 'studentlist', 'code': 16}}
```

How can I manipulate through the data and get a result like this :

```
if age == 23 then return thomas and jennie as output and store it in a variable as string.
```

NOTE : It should iterate through the whole data and search for age, I am using the "for each" loop for this but not working.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: That's not JSON. It looks like the `repr()` representation of Python dict objects. Do you infact have said objects already at hand? Also please include your non-working "for each loop" in the question.

Comment: A `for` loop should do it. Post what you tried and we can work from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you already have the JSON parsed into an object, so you can just iterate through it and check the person's age.

```
dictionary = {
    'Namelist': {
        'thomas': {'gender': 'male', 'age': '23'},
        'david': {'gender':  'male'},
        'jennie': {'gender': 'female', 'age': '23'},
        'alex': {'gender': 'male'}},
    'selectors': {'naming': 'studentlist', 'code': 16}}


# For Loop Method
name_list = []
for name, person in dictionary['Namelist'].items():
    if person.get('age') == '23':
        name_list.append(name)
print(', '.join(name_list)) # Would print 'thomas, jennie'


# List Comprehension Method
name_list = [name for name, person in dictionary['Namelist'].items() if person.get('age') == '23']
print(', '.join(name_list))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick and dirty way that I'd do it.  You can get into list comprehension as well, but I thought this was easier for you to understand as a newbie. It works in python 3 as well as I use the brackets for print().

```
variable = {'Namelist': {'thomas': {'gender': 'male', 'age': '23'}, 
'david': {'gender':  'male'}, 'jennie': {'gender': 'female', 'age': 
'23'}, 'alex': {'gender': 'male'}}, 'selectors': {'naming': 
'studentlist', 'code': 16}}

response = list() #Create a list to use to store the iterations.
for key, value in variable.items():  #Loop through the main dictionary
  if key == 'Namelist': #Filter by the NameList
    for theName, subValue in value.items(): #Loop through the dictionaries made for each name.
      if 'age' in subValue and subValue['age'] == '23':  #the age key wasn't in every dictionary so I check if it exists, then I check if it is set to 23.
        response.append(theName + ' is 23 ') #add it to the response list.
    nameString = ''.join(response) #turn the list into a string.
    print (nameString) #print it
```